# Windows Mobile 7 Blog

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, c#

I am looking for any blog/rss/newsgroup for bleeding edge Windows Mobile 7 news and/or coding.

Does anyone know a good one to follow?

Comment: This question will probably be closed, unfortunately. Try asking a slightly different question: "Tips and tricks for coding for Windows Mobile 7?" Some people will respond with answers that include links to blogs and such.

Answer (score 1):

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsmobile

The official name is Windows Phone 7 Series.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [NewzCrawler](http://www.newzcrawler.com/index.shtml)?

> NewzCrawler is a rss/atom reader, news aggregator, browser and blog client for Windows which provides access to news content from various sources.